# MicrosoftMvcValidation.js VS jquery.validate.js (Bassistance)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a previous MVC 2.0 application, I included (in my Site.Master) a reference to the CDN file of `jquery.validate.min.js` for all my client-side validation.

I’m now creating an MVC 3.0 project and I’m a bit confused with the amount of articles written about `“how to use client-side validation using MicrosoftMvcValidation.js”.`

In most (if not all) articles, when I see a reference to `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js` I also see a reference to `jquery.validate.js` which is kind of confusing (considering, in the past, I’ve only used bassistance’s file).

So my questions are:

- What is the difference between these two files?
- Are there any known issues/benefits in using one over the other?
- Inside the “`Scripts`” folder, by default, it looks like both files
  are there but why? Do they give us the choice or do they work hand in
  hand?

Any help shedding some light on this would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MVC3 supports two modes of client-side validation:

- Classical validation using MicrosoftMvcValidation.js
  To enable this, call `Html.EnableClientValidation()` before `Html.BeginForm()`.
- Unobtrusive validation using jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js (new to MVC3)
  To enable this, add the following settinsg to Web.config:

  ```
  <appSettings>
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  ```

Comment: Ok so basically, all these files are provided in the *Scripts* folder in order to give you the choice between M$’s way or Bassistance’s way right? Are there any known issues in using one over the other or it all comes down to preference? Thanks SLaks

Comment: @Vlince: Correct.  The MVC3 is newer and cleaner; the old scripts are provided for compatibility with existing MVC2 projects.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, I will definitely continue using the jQuery approach for the reasons Stephen mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

MVC2 provided the choice between Microsoft's own client-side validation, or jQuery validation.

MVC3 continues this, but only provides unobtrusive validation (i.e. new HTML5 validation features) if you go down the jQuery route.

In both cases, the prevailing opinion seems to be that jQuery is the better choice, as it is more easily extended and simpler to use. There is no need to include both scripts in either your project or your webpage - typically, you would choose one and delete the other.

Comment: Indeed, the jQuery route does seem like a better choice. More importantly if you also plan on using the new HTML5 validation features. Thanks Stephen.